# Debug ionic3 app for building it with --prod flag

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

For a while, I didn't build my ionic3 app with `--prod` flag, it used to work fine, but I've made quite a few changes since that. Now when I run `ionic cordova build android --prod` I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.unescapeIdentifier (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:10550:26)
    at getTextOfNode (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68575:27)
    at emitIdentifier (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66931:19)
    at pipelineEmitUnspecified (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66594:28)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66566:50)
    at pipelineEmitWithSourceMap (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66558:17)
    at emitNodeWithComments (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:64200:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66547:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithNotification (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66541:17)
    at emit (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66528:13)
```

The app builds and run fine without `--prod` flag.

I understand the problem comes from an undefined property that could not be read and therefore typescript refuse to compile the code.

My problem is that I've no idea where that `length` property is in my app, since there are plenty of them.
Is there a way to get more info about where that property is situated in my code, from typescript or ionic, so that I can correct this error and be able to build the app with `--prod` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem with one of your `node_modules` item or items. So **delete** `node_modules` folder and then run `npm i`

Comment: Thanks, it solved that problem but created many others. Still can't build but getting other error messages. Also I got many errors from `npm i`. I'll post another question related to those issues.

Comment: I highly suggest you to upgrade your app to latest `ionic 3.9.2` : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases